# putting "*" values in a dialog box C# forms

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I am using the simple `Dialog` box given in the following link as a crude (that's all I need) password input box:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox-class/

How do I set the text to display `****` instead of the password?

Comment: Web app or winform app ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that control you have a TextBox, set the [`PasswordChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx) property of the textbox to `*`.

Also see: How to: [Create a Password Text Box with the Windows Forms TextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3223ht2.aspx)

In your control's show method, after defining that textbox, add:

```
textBox.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Comment: `+1` for being the fastest gun in the west.

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`How to: Create a Password Text Box with the Windows Forms TextBox Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3223ht2.aspx)

> To create a password text box
>
> - Set the `PasswordChar` property of the `TextBox` control to a **specific character**. The `PasswordChar` property specifies the character displayed
>     in the text box. For example, if you want asterisks displayed in the
>     password box, specify `*` for the `PasswordChar` property in the
>     `Properties` window. Then, regardless of what character a user types in
>     the text box, an asterisk is displayed.

```
// The password character is an asterisk.
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

From [`TextBox.PasswordChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx) property

> Gets or sets the character used to mask characters of a password in a
>   single-line TextBox control.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Just set that property on your text box and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From the property window in windows forms

[image]